# Site Returned HTTP Code:301 - link exchange

Tags: seo, backlinks

Hey there, I have a link exchange script, and for a few weeks - after it verify's a site i'm exchanging links - the script tells me:

Site Returned HTTP Code:301

What does that mean?
TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP code 301 is "Moved permanently". This means that the redirect is permanent.

In your case, it's likely to confirm that the affiliate link works as expected (redirects to an other site).

Answer (score 4):

That means the URL you are attempting to check is now redirecting to a new/different URL.

To get a full list of http codes, see Wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes.